# swing: best way to make components enabled/disabled depending on the state of a model

Tags: model-view-controller, swing

I have a data model `model` which has a boolean flag `connected`, and I have a view with several components that I want to enable if `model.isConnected()` is true and disable if it is not. What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your model accept [PropertyChangeListener](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html)s (perhaps by delegating to a [PropertyChangeSupport](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html)). Fire a [PropertyChangeEvent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeEvent.html) whenever the `connected` state changes. Have the components listen to that property change, and change their visual state as appropriate.

Comment: when to use PropertyChangeSupport vs. SwingPropertyChangeSupport?

Comment: Good point! I wasn't familiar with SwingPropertyChangeSupport. As long as you fire your property changes from within the event thread, you should be ok with SwingPropertyChangeSupport.

Comment: hmm, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: "This subclass of java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport is identical in functionality -- it sacrifices thread-safety (not a Swing concern) for reduce memory consumption, which helps performance (both big Swing concerns). Most of the overridden methods are only necessary because all of PropertyChangeSupport's instance data is private, without accessor methods."